# What is the meaning of the entry `("%T" file t t nil t)` defined in the AucTeX variable `TeX-expand-list-builtin`

Tags: auctex

`AucTeX` uses the two variables `TeX-expand-list` and `TeX-expand-list-builtin` when processing (La)TeX buffers.

According to the documentation of the  variable `TeX-expand-list`

> ...
>   Each entry is a list with two or more elements.  The first
>   element is the string to be expanded.  The second element is the
>   name of a function returning the expanded string when called with
>   the remaining elements as arguments.  The special value ‘file’
>   will be expanded to the name of the file being processed, with an
>   optional extension.

With only this information in hands I am enable to figure out what is the expansion of the string `"%T"` by applying the rule `("%T" file t t nil t)` as well as the expansion of the strings `"%s"` and `"%t"` by applying ("%s" file nil t) and  ("%t" file t t) defined in `TeX-expand-list-builtin`

Comment: `TeX-command-expand` replaces temporarily the value of its `file` argument with `TeX--master-or-region-file-with-extra-quotes`. See the doc string of that function. Note that the `file` argument is used for the expansion of the special value `file` in `TeX-expand-list`.

Comment: Note, that the last sentence in the description text of your question looks somewhat strange. It looks like you had already answered the question yourself. But, comparing your statement with the code of `tex-buf.el` I can imagine that you have not. I only mention that because maybe that identifies the reason why your question does not have an answer yet.

Comment: @Tobias Thank you for your reply. The goal of my question is to figure out what is the final expansion of the string `"%`%l%(mode)%' %T"` which is associated to `"LaTeX"` command in `TeX-command-list` according to `TeX-expand-list-builtin`. I am sorry for my English.

Comment: Did you have a look at the help for `TeX--master-or-region-file-with-extra-quotes`? That explains what the arguments to the `file` command, i.e., `t t nil t` mean.